# how to skip lines that already exist in a file?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I know, it seems like a simple problem, but please read my question.

I want to extract html class names that match the following pattern:

```
regex = re.compile(r'([\w-]+)-([#\w\d,%()\.]+)')
```

and write it as a CSS style in a different file.

for that, I have a dictionary of the values and properties that we're going to use:

```
keyword = {
'c':'color',
'bg':'background',
'red':'#ed1a1a',
'blue':'#60a8ff'
#etc
}
```

example:

the html file: `<div class="c-red bg-blue"> content </div>`

output in css file:

```
.c-red{
color: red;
}
.bg-blue{
background: blue;
}
```

and here's my script that basically does it:

```
regex = re.compile(r'([\w-]+)-([#\w\d,%()\.]+)')
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
  with open('style.css', 'a+') as newfile:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'class="' in line:
          to_replace = regex.findall(line)
          for key in to_replace:         
              prop=key[0]  
              value=key[1] 
              name='.'+prop+'-'+value
              if prop and value in keyword:
                var1 =('\n'+name+'{'+
                  '\n'+keyword[prop]+': '+
                  keyword[value]+';'+
                  '\n'+'}')
                newfile.write(var1)
```

**BUT**
if I have multiple similar HTML strings, like:

```
<div class="c-red bg-blue"> content </div>
<div class="c-red bg-blue"> content2 </div>
<div class="c-red bg-blue"> content2 </div>
```

the script will write CSS commands as many times as there are strings in the HTML file.

how do I prevent this duplication?

i have tried:

`var1=''`

and

```
if var1 in newfile:
  break
else:
  newfile.write(var1)
```

but none of these working.

Comment: Are you aware about [BeatyfulSoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) ?

Comment: Problem is in this `if var1 in newfile:` newfile is not content of new file. If you want content you have to read this file.

Comment: @Matej yes i tried it in `a+` mode.

Comment: Just store the var1s 's in a set or something then check if they are in prior to writing.

Comment: @valeria Yes, that's right but you have to read this file, like `if var1 in newfile.read()` but it's not very effective.

Comment: @Matej oh. just tried it. Doesn't work either

Comment: @ilamaaa I don't quite get it.? can you please show me

Comment: @valeria File is not maybe flushed, better way is to store appended data also in variable and this variable use to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your write add append to a set. Then simply check the set prior to writing. This won't check items written to the newfile previously

```
written = set()

regex = re.compile(r'([\w-]+)-([#\w\d,%()\.]+)')
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
  with open('style.css', 'a+') as newfile:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'class="' in line:
          to_replace = regex.findall(line)
          for key in to_replace:         
              prop=key[0]  
              value=key[1] 
              name='.'+prop+'-'+value
              if prop and value in keyword:
                var1 =('\n'+name+'{'+
                  '\n'+keyword[prop]+': '+
                  keyword[value]+';'+
                  '\n'+'}')
                if var1 not in written: #check if you already wrote it
                    newfile.write(var1) # if not write it
                    written.add(var1) # you wrote it so add it the list of things you check against
```

Comment: oh this one seems to work much better in my case! thanks

Comment: @Matej true, ill add as a note

Answer (score 2):

I edited your code:

```
import re

keyword = {
'c':'color',
'bg':'background',
'red':'#ed1a1a',
'blue':'#60a8ff'
#etc
}

regex = re.compile(r'([\w-]+)-([#\w\d,%()\.]+)')
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
    with open('style.css', 'a+') as newfile:
        content = newfile.read()

        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
                if 'class="' in line:
                    to_replace = regex.findall(line)
                    for key in to_replace:
                            name='.'+key[0]+'-'+key[1]
                            prop=key[0] 
                            value=key[1] 
                            if prop and value in keyword:
                                var1 =('\n'+name+'{'+ '\n' + keyword[prop] + ': ' + keyword[value] + ';' + '\n'+'}')

                                if not var1 in content:
                                    newfile.write(var1)
                                    content += var1
```

`content = newfile.read()` will read content of file with style and save it to the varaible. Then at every new `var1` it will try to find it in `content` and if `var1` is not here, it will write it to the file and append it to the `content` variable.

Output:

```
.c-red{
color: #ed1a1a;
}
.bg-blue{
background: #60a8ff;
}
```